# NSDecimalNumber, NSDecimalNumberHandler, and threads

Tags: objective-c, ios

I write a finance-based application, and I need custom behavior for NSDecimalNumber operations, so I call `[NSDecimalNumber setDefaultBehavior:(MyHandlerSubclass)]` on application launch. However, I just found out from the NSDecimalNumber header file that it needs to be called *on each thread* decimal number calculations might be run on.

I could explicitly call `[(NSDecimalNumber *) performOperation:withBehavior:]`, passing my MyHandlerSubclass each time, but it grows verbose and tiring. Is there any way to eliminate the verbosity, maintain the setDefaultBehavior:, and not have to worry about calculations being done on different threads with the wrong behavior? It sounds like I'd have to write my own wrapper to do so.

Comment: How often are you using threads in your application? Generally, you want the main thread, and maybe 1-2 worker threads, but no more. Your code should not grow tedious if you implement your threads correctly, you also may want to check out `NSRunLoop`, `NSOperationQueue` and `GCD`, instead of threads.

Comment: Richard: this isn't a question about how to best use threads, I know about all of those. I'm using GCD queues extensively, and there's no guarantee what thread they're running on, as you know.

Comment: Same applies to queues;  you (a) shouldn't be scheduling dozens or hundreds of blocks in the global concurrent queues and (b) shouldn't have more than a few other queues within the app (which is really just another form of (a)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I write a finance-based application, and I need custom behavior for
>   NSDecimalNumber operations, so I call [NSDecimalNumber
>   setDefaultBehavior:(MyHandlerSubclass)] on application launch.
>   However, I just found out from the NSDecimalNumber header file that it
>   needs to be called on each thread decimal number calculations might be
>   run on.

That seems unmanageable in the context of queues.  There is no guarantee what thread any given GCD queue might run on, be it one of your own creation or one of the system provided queues.  (Obviously, the main queue is an exception to this rule).

The documentation says nothing about this limitation.  Either the docs are wrong or the header is wrong...

... and it is the docs (Disassembly is my friend).   File a bug.

There doesn't seem to be a way to avoid using the more verbose form save for calling +setDefaultBehavior: at the beginning of any scheduled block (to cover the arbitrary thread issue).

File a bug asking for an enhancement as the current behavior doesn't make sense in a queue based world (and put the bug # here, please).

Comment: Done, 10898798 (filed it before I read your response, so the language is a bit rough as I was still unsure if I was missing something, but it gets the point across). Thanks for confirming the issue, I always feel a bit daft when I bump into odd issues like this, because I'm unsure if it's me not knowing a technique, header files being wrong, or documentation being wrong.